# Conflicting issues with position: relative;

Tags: html, css

I recently edited the way a template was designed for MyBB. Fortunately, I made it exactly how I expected it to look, however, the navigation bar seemed broke. After trying to navigate, I realized that I could only click on the lower half of the navigation.
http://gyazo.com/99337bd5252b37e118ce119d5168bcf3
As you can see where I painted the red boxes is the only place where the link activation works. After about 2 hours I found out my problem was due to a "position: relative;". When I remove it, the navigation works fine but my panel div becomes moved all the way to the right and out of position.

```
<div class="main-bg">
<div class="main-width">

    <a name="top" id="top"></a>

    <div class="top-bar blue-texture"></div>

    <div id="header">


      <div id="panel">
 {$welcomeblock}
      </div>


      <div class="logo" >
         <a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/index.php"><img src="{$theme['logo']}" alt="{$mybb- >settings['bbname']}" title="{$mybb->settings['bbname']}" /></a>
</div>
      <hr class="hidden" />
     </div>
  </div>
  </div>
   <div id="container">
<div class="bg-img">
 </div>
    <hr class="hidden" />

    <div class="menu blue-texture">

            <span class="search">
    <form action="search.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="do_search" />
        <input type="hidden" name="postthread" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="forums" value="all" />
        <input type="hidden" name="showresults" value="threads" />
        <input type="text" name="keywords" value="search..." onfocus="if(this.value == 'search...') { this.value = ''; }" onblur="if(this.value=='') { this.value='search...'; }" size="22" />
        <input type="submit" value="Go" class="search-button" title="Search the forums" />
    </form>
            </span>

     <ul>
      <li><a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/page.php?page=tournaments">Tournaments</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

There is the complete code on how I have developed this. However, the problem is mainly in the CSS.

```
#header {
    padding: 60px 0 85px;
    height: 56px;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
}

#panel {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #07090b;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute; 
    top:0; 
    margin-top: 0px;
    right: 0;
    padding-top: 4px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    height: 130px;
    }
.menu {
     border-radius: 6px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     border: 1px solid #174d7b!important;
     height: 50px;
     }
```

I can't find a way to fix the problem however, because there is no way to add position:relative; and make the navigation links still work as they are intended to.

Comment: I think the `div#header` is over the `ul` but I need to see it for real or a more complete html/css to test it. You can check with the Chrome Developer Tool (F12) et inspect the `div#header` to see where it ends.

Comment: More CSS would def be helpful

Comment: A fiddle would help.

Answer (score 1):

Without actual link or a working snippet it would be hard to find the issue, but please try this css that may solve your problem:

```
.menu { width: 100%; }
.menu ul li a { display: inline-block; width: auto; float: left; }
```

Hope this helps